# Updating database table & column

Tags: entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-4

Using MVC4 and EF Code First

I renamed my table/column-name i.e. table: from Categories to Category in the model and in the code and when I run the migration statement

```
Update-Database -Verbose -Force
```

I get an error:

> The CREATE UNIQUE INDEX statement terminated because a duplicate key was found for the object name 'dbo.Categories' and the index name 'PK_dbo.Categories'. The duplicate key value is (). Could not create constraint. See previous errors. The statement has been terminated.

In the configuration file I have `AutomaticMigrationsEnabled = true;`

Is there something else I need to do to make the changes apply in the database?

Comment: Did you rename PK too ?

Comment: yes i have. anything else should I check?

Comment: I have edited your title. Please see, "[Should questions include “tags” in their titles?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/)", where the consensus is "no, they should not".

Answer (score 2):

You cannot modify the PK.

1 - Delete existing database then run `Update-Database`

2 - Generate update script by running `Update-Database -Script` and add drop index TSQL to generated file and run the script.

3 - Remove key constrain from table via Visual Studio or Management Studio then remove TSQL for dropping index in generated script then run script.

Comment: I dont want to delete the database. I have data already in the tables. There is no way to rename it? When I try to generate the script 'PM> update-database -Script -Force' -> error: User canceled out of save dialog (Exception from HRESULT: 0x8004000C (OLE_E_PROMPTSAVECANCELLED))

Comment: 1-backup your database 2-restore it on new database 3-delete database 4- run `Update-Database` 5-insert data from backup table to generated database table by EF